# Display UK Date format in Advanced Filter Mode fields within PowerView for SharePoint

Tags: sql-server, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, datepicker, powerview

Follow this link for video of the issue: http://screencast.com/t/PsvTTe3Yryx
(**NB the field should read 27/2/2014 (which is UK date format).**)

## ISSUE

I am currently building a BI Application using PowerView for SharePoint. I am based in the UK so end-users expect to see UK Dates.

Generally, PowerView shows correct UK Dates eg in LIST FILTER MODE.

However, it shows US Dates in ADVANCED FILTER MODE.

## QUESTION

- How do I fix this?
- Could this be due to SharePoint 2010?

## CONTEXT

The PowerView application will be used by many users with varying skill levels.

Having US Dates AND UK Dates will no doubt add to the confusion and lead to a negative User Experience, which we (all) wish to avoid.

I look forward to your feedback, Experts!

JohnAeris

Answer (score 0):

Go to Site Settings->Regional Settings and set locale to **English (United Kingdom)**